# Attributes category in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, oop, magento

I'm trying to add some attributes to categories. These attributes I would like to change in admin->catalog->manage categories. I found many tutorials but none works on magento 1.7.
I used follow module but no results
[here is the module](http://atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/)

**Initial configuration file is located in ‘app/etc/modules/Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute.xml’.
Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
   <modules>
    <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
   </modules>
</config>
```

**Module configuration file is located in 'app/code/community/Atwix/CustomCategoryAttribute/etc/config.xml’.
config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
  </modules>

<global>
    <resources>
        <add_category_attribute>
            <setup>
                <module>Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </add_category_attribute>
        <add_category_attribute_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </add_category_attribute_write>
        <add_category_attribute_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </add_category_attribute_read>
    </resources>
</global>
</config>
```

The script is located in 'app/code/community/Atwix/CustomCategoryAttribute/sql/add_category_attribute/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php’

```
  <?php
  $this->startSetup();
  $this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Custom attribute',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL));

 $this->endSetup();
```

Can somebody help me? I can't find any errors in my module. Perhaps exists some module which debug modules? or how can I get errors?

SOLVED:

I changed the version of module to 1.0.0. This was enough to rerun script's initializing of module: 'app/code/community/Atwix/CustomCategoryAttribute/sql/add_category_attribute/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php’

1. config.xml

   <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
   1.0.0
   </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
2. rename mysql4-install-0.0.1.php to mysql4-install-1.0.0.php

Comment: The code looks fine. Did you clear the cache?

Comment: I disabled the Cache. I clear the cache. I think the problem with magento version.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Yes. The code is fine. I changed the version of module.